# Get the latest 10 articles on a specified node type?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

now, if the node type is article. on the term page's left,  i want to show the latest 10 articles's title  which  node type is article. i don't want to use views, how do i do? thank you.

if i want to show the latest 10 articles's title  which  node type is article on the node page's left . how to write the query. many thanks.

ps:i found EntityFieldQuery maybe can do this, but i don't now how to do out put it.

my code:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query
 ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
 ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
 ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
 ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC')
  ->range(0, 10);

$result = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code can be something like that (using [db_select()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7))

```
$query = db_select("node", "n") // select from the node table
    ->fields("n", array("nid", "title")) // fields nid, title
    ->condition("type", "page", "=") // where the node type = page
    ->orderBy("created", "DESC") // order by the newest
    ->range(0, 10) // select only 10 records
    ->execute(); // execute the query

while($record = $query->fetchAssoc()) {
    print(l($record['title'], "node/" . $record['nid'])); // print the node title linked to node.
}
```

Another example using [EntityFieldQuery()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7):

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')          
      ->entityCondition('bundle', 'club')
      ->propertyOrderBy("created", "DESC")
      ->range(0, 10)
      ->execute();

foreach($entities['node'] as $obj)
{
    $node = node_load($obj->nid);
    print(l($node->title, "node/" . $node->nid));
}
```

Performance wise: use the first method.

Comment: thank you,i found EntityFieldQuery is also can do that, but i don't now how to use it. thank you

Comment: I have added an example for this case.

Comment: i am sorry, i put the db_select code in page.tpl.php it shows Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: i now the query condition, but i don't know how to print the result?

Comment: db_select() the first method

Comment: Use the `while loop` to print the results. I have updated the answer.

Comment: how to print the $entities result, if i want to output the articles titles.

Comment: db_select() method is right. if i want to the title as link, how to do?  how to print the second method result?many thanks

Comment: got it,how to print the second method result?

Answer (score 3):

Another solution I'll mention since if it is good Drupal knowledge. The Views module can create a block like this with very little work. It is a bit tricky to learn but it is very much meant for making these kinds of listings.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of D7 performance you're probably better off using the old `db_query` command:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = :type AND status = 1 ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10", array(':type' => $type));
foreach ($result as $record) {
  // Do something with each $record
  $node = node_load($record->nid);
}
```

For a speed comparison of `db_query` and `db_select` look here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1067802#comment-8996571

> For simple queries, db_query() is 22% faster than db_select()
>
> For simple queries, db_query() is 124% faster than EFQ
>
> For queries with two joins, db_query() is 29% faster than db_select()

This is because db_select and EntityFieldQuery() allow modules to hook in and modify the query.  Which may be a good thing for you!

I'm just providing options.